# SSH by LDAP groups - not work

Tags: centos, ssh, ldap

There are "31" servers configured from the same RedOS image (CentOS 7-based). They are entered into the LDAP samba domain, and are configured for authorization via ssh based on ldap user groups. For this purpose the following have been changed:

created as root

```
echo "Domain admins" > /etc/ssh/access_groups.conf && chmod 600 /etc/ssh/access_groups.conf
```

modified /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
____missed default____
account required pam_nologin.so
account sufficient pam_localuser.so
account required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/ssh/access_groups.conf
account include password-auth
_______ missed default____
```

visudo /etc/sudoers.d/01-domain-users

```
#sudo admin users LDAP auth
"%mydomain.local\Domain admins" ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

systemctl restart sshd

This configuration has been successfully applied to about 30 servers and is working. On server 31 the configuration does not work.
When trying to log in, the client side displays connection closed by server.

```
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
t1_rushao@ruyansvap38's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 10.65.201.61 port 22
```

On server side

```
sshd[18238]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.65.90.176 user=t1_rushao
sshd[18238]: pam_listfile(sshd:account): Refused user t1_rushao for service sshd
sshd[18238]: Failed password for t1_rushao from 10.65.90.176 port 59786 ssh2
sshd[18238]: fatal: Access denied for user t1_rushao by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

If I comment out *"account required pam_listfile.so..."* I can connect via ssh as a domain user, but sudo doesn't work either. At the same time,

```
id t1_rushao
uid=1006007868(t1_rushao) gid=1006000513(domain users) groups=1006000513(domain users),1006000512(domain admins)
```

The sssd service is working, authorization by the domain users on server also seems to be working, I tried kinit, net ads join several times. /etc/security/access.conf is completely commented out by default.

I have run out of ideas why this configuration does not work personally on this server. I understand that the problem is somewhere in the domain groups, the system cannot match the user’s groups with the settings, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible character case issue: the `id` command reports the group as `domain admins` in all-lowercase, but your `/etc/ssh/access_groups.conf` and `/etc/sudoers.d/01-domain-users` both have the group specified as `Domain admins` with initial upper-case.

Unix/Linux systems are generally case-sensitive, and I find no reason to believe that `pam_listfile.so` would be an exception to this rule. I know that `sudo` definitely is case-sensitive.

Try changing the group name in both `access_groups.conf` and in the sudoers configuration to all-lowercase, to match the exact case reported by `id`.

The configuration of `sssd` (`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` and any `/etc/sssd/conf.d/*.conf` files) might have some differences in the configuration of e.g. the domain's `full_name_format`, `use_fully_qualified_names` or `case_sensitive` settings.

Your working servers obviously must have `case_sensitive = false`, which seems not to be the default of sssd - perhaps the non-working server is missing some of these settings?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I tried to specify in `/etc/ssh/access_groups.conf` in three options: domain admins
MYDOMAIN\domain admins
MYDOMAIN.LOCAL\domain admins
but it doesn't work.

Judging by other servers, `pam_listfile.so` is not case sensitive, authorization works for groups like `SRV-some-Name-HeRe`, although the id command displays as `srv-some-name-here`.

There was a peculiarity on two servers: sudo groups in the `“%MYDOMAIN\Domain admins”` format did not work; they only worked when I specified it simply as `“%Domain admins”`. But I didn't understand why this was required.

Answer (score 0):

**telcoM**, exactly! It really worked.
On the last server, `sssd.conf` differs from the others with just one additional line.

`re_expression = (?P<name>[a-z0-9._-]+)`

On other servers there is no such line.
And on all servers have the sssd.conf setting `case_sensitive = False`

I did the analysis, and this file is automatically configured by the `join-to-domain` script package from the RedOS development team that adds servers to the LDAP domain. Just a few days ago a new version of the script was released, and on this server (which was created a couple of days ago) the sssd configuration is different from the others.

As a result, 2 conditions coincided at once: `Domain admins` separated by a space, and the sssd configuration became case-sensitive. I have tested on simple-named groups, and checked on lowercase-configured group names and it works with it.
I disabled `re_expression` and everything worked with `Domain admins` group and any case insensitive configs. It will be necessary to ask the developers why this was done.